# Substring for number on a cell

Tags: matlab

I have an array of numbers like this:

```
My_array= [19 52 89 34 75 62]
```

What I want to do is: 
First, take the value cell by cell. For example, the first one would be : 19

After that, I want to save the first digit of the number (1) in a variable and the second digit (9) in another variable

I'm trying to do this with the following code:

```
   for i=1:6
       element=my_array{i};
       elmt=num2str(element);
       var1=substring(elmt,1,1);
       var2=substring(elmt,2,1);
   end
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error :  undefined function 'substring' for input arguments of type 'char'
```

So, my questions are:
  **At the beggining the type of each element is cell, isn't ?** 
**Is there any function to convert from cell to string ?**
Otherwise, why is my element considered a char and not a String?
How can I modify my code for the purpose described above ?
Thanks!

Comment: Matlab has no "string" type as such, only `char` arrays. There's also no `substring` function, hence the error that says so. There's [perfectly good documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/data-types_data-types.html) that explains all of this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
My_array= [19 52 89 34 75 62]; %%// Input
arr1 = int2str(My_array)-'0'; %%// Separate the digits
arr1 = arr1(arr1~=-16); %%// Remove the numbers that represent the spaces between digits and numbers(-16)
arr1 = reshape(arr1,2,[])'; %%//' Reshape the digits into a Nx2 matrix
var1 = arr1(:,1); %%// Get the first digits into var1
var2 = arr1(:,2); %%// Get the second digits into var2
```

Comment: For all that, you may as well just do `var1=floor(My_array/10); var2=mod(My_array,10);` ;)

Comment: Q2: What if my array was My_array= ['19' '52' '89' '34' '75' '62'];
should I just use after that num2str ? (don't work in this case)
I've build mu array like that : array{end+1}=str2num(strcat(num2str(i),num2str(j)));
thanks !

Comment: @ranell Try this then - `out = reshape(My_array,2,[]) - '0'; var1 = out(1,:); var2 = out(2,:);`.

Comment: not yet, i've this error about the minus '0' : undefined function 'minus' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Comment: So, you meant `My_array` is a cell array and not a double array as you have put there. So, for a cell case, do this - `My_array1 = vertcat(My_array{:}); out = My_array1-'0'; var1 = out(:,1); var2 = out(:,2);`

Comment: @Notlikethat I guess in a double digit case, it's easier to just use `floor` and `mod`, but in big number cases, it's easier to hold all the digits in a place as a matrix :)